# How to use super() in an awaitable subclass?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'd like to add a new functionality to an existing awaitable class by subclassing it.

Let's start with a very simple base class creating objects which asynchronously return 99 after a short sleep. The subclass should just add +1 to the result.

I can't find the proper way to use `super()` to refer to the base class.

```
import asyncio

class R99:
    def __await__(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        fut = loop.create_future()
        loop.call_later(0.5, fut.set_result, 99)
        return fut.__await__()

class R100(R99):
    async def add1(self):
        v = await R99()
        #v = await super().__await__()   # <== error
        return v + 1

    def __await__(self):
        return self.add1().__await__()

async def test():
    print(await R99())
    print(await R100())

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(test())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [await method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__await__) must return an iterator, so you can make it a generator and use the [yield from](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) syntax:

```
class R100(R99):

    def __await__(self):
        v = yield from super().__await__()
        return v + 1
```

Comment: And I thought `await` is the new `yield from`. Now I see it is not that simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are allowed to modify `R99`, you can make `__await__()` invoke an actual coroutine, which can chain to `super()` in the regular way:

```
import asyncio

class R99:
    async def await_coro(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        fut = loop.create_future()
        loop.call_later(0.5, fut.set_result, 99)
        return await fut

    def __await__(self):
        return self.await_coro().__await__()

class R100(R99):
    async def await_coro(self):
        v = await super().await_coro()
        return v + 1
```

If that is not an option, @Vincent's answer precisely explains how to chain from one `__await__` to another. Note that you were quite correct in thinking that `await` is the new `yield from` - it is, and there is normally no reason to use `yield from` in newly written asyncio code. (This of course doesn't apply to non-asyncio-related generators that delegate to sub-generators; those are welcome to keep using `yield from`.)

However, by implementing `__await__()` you are dropping into the lower-level API which uses generators to implement coroutines. At this level `yield` suspends the coroutine, returning control to the event loop, and `yield from` delegates to another generator that implements a coroutine. In new code the only valid purpose for this layer is to implement an awaitable object without using the interpreter, e.g. in Python/C or Cython. This is done by providing an `__await__` that returns an iterator, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51115745/1600898). The resulting object is equivalent to an `async def`.